# Escaping quotes and/or backslashes in a given string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to escape one or several of the following characters in a given string: ', " and \

I have attempted to do this with regular expressions, which works fine, but not in javascript seeing as how the engine is very limited feature-wise.

The problem is basically it needs to handle pre-escaped sequences. See examples below:

```
foo"bar  --->  foo\"bar
foo\"bar --->  foo\"bar
foo\\"bar -->  foo\\\"bar
foo\\\"bar ->  foo\\\"bar
```

Etc. Same logic applies for the single quotes and backslashes too.

Can anybody point me in the right direction of how to acheive this in javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will [this built-in function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) do the trick for you?

Comment: In what context and for what purpose are you trying to escape the characters? The question is unanswerable without that information, as there are many different possible answers.

Comment: @Pointy: I am merely trying to output sanitized data. I will not be using it for anything in particular, but I want the output to be correct and sanitized.

Comment: Right, but: where is this "sanitation" happening - on the server? in other JavaScript code? And what is the target of the sanitation: the JavaScript parser itself? HTML? Something else?

Comment: To sanitize or escape you have to know what you're escaping *for*. There's no obvious context in common Javascript where this kind of manual escaping is necessary. So please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = ["foo\"bar", "foo\\\"bar", "foo\\\\bar", "foo\\\\\"bar",
           "foo\\bar", "foo\\\\\\bar"];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  console.log(arr[i] + " -> " + arr[i].replace(/\\?([\\'"])/g, "\\$1"));
}
```

yields

`foo"bar -> foo\"bar`
`foo\"bar -> foo\"bar`
`foo\\bar -> foo\\bar`
`foo\\"bar -> foo\\\"bar`
`foo\bar -> foo\\bar`
`foo\\\bar -> foo\\\\bar`

`/\\?([\\'"])/g` matches one of the characters you listed optionally preceded by a backslash and `"\\$1"` replaces it with a mandatory backslash followed by the character to escape.

Comment: If you run this expression at say something like `\n` which should be left untouched, it gets turned into `\\n`

Comment: You didn't ask for that behaviour. just change `[\\'"]` to contain all of your chars that are allowed to be escaped `[\\'"rn]`, etc. **+1 because this is a RegExp solution that works in JavaScript.**

Answer (score 1):

If you can't figure out how to do it with a RegExp, why not write a function?

```
function esc(s) {
    var out = '', i, escaped = 0, c;
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) { // loop over string
        c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c === '\\') escaped = 1 - escaped; // get escaped state
        else {
            if (c === "'" || c === '"') { // if quote
                if (escaped === 0) out += '\\'; // escape if not escaped
                else escaped = 0; // else reset escaped state
            } else if (escaped) out += '\\', escaped = 0; // else close escape
        }
        out += c;
        // console.log(s, i, c, escaped, out);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Now

```
esc('foo"bar');       // foo"bar    -> foo\"bar
esc('foo\\"bar');     // foo\"bar   -> foo\"bar
esc('foo\\\\"bar');   // foo\\"bar  -> foo\\\"bar
esc('foo\\\\\\"bar'); // foo\\\"bar -> foo\\\"bar
```

---

*JavaScript* does offer two (standard) native functions which can achieve a sanitised result (though different to the above). These are [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), with the reverse being `decodeURI` and `decodeURIComponent`, respectively. Depending on what you want to do with your strings, these functions may be preferable.

I'll also add that if you want to sanitise a string to protect your server, do the sanitisation server-side, as you can't trust any data coming from a client's machine to be safe, even if you have client-side sanitisation.

Comment: I was mainly checking if there was a nifty way of doing it, or perhaps any build in functions I did not know about. Either way, I have gotten two great answers I can base my new code off of.